# How to make trigger with only 10 inputs in one week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I want to make a `trigger` that checks if the `employee` has not more than 10 `questionid's` in a week(in the contentment table).
The employee may not answer more than 10 questions in a week(7 days).
Is this possible?

> **Contentmenttable**: employeeid, questionid, date, score

I'm struggling how to get a weekly function.

`Create table` script **contentment**:

```
create table contentment
(
employeeid int,
questionid int,
date date,
score char(5) not null,

constraint pk_contentment primary key (medewerkernr, vraagid, datum),
constraint fk_contentment_employeeid foreign key (employeeid) references employee(employeeid),
constraint fk_contentment_questionid foreign key (questionid) references question(questionid),
)
```

`Inserts` **contentment** table:

```
1,1, '10-11-2018', null
2,1, '10-11-2018', null
2,2, '11-11-2018', null
2,3, '12-11-2018', null
2,4, '13-11-2018', null
2,5, '14-11-2018', null
```

`Null` because the `employee` needs to add a `score` to it.

Comment: You probably need triggers for this.

Comment: Are we talking about a calendar week (Monday through Sunday) or just the last 7 days?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, a calendar week.

Comment: Can you share the complete DDL (create table statement) for the table?

Comment: I added it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is what should happen when some employee already reached the maximum questions count and a new one is inserted. Should you raise and error and reject the new record? Or do not change this table and write the insert in a different table? Or anything else? I will assume you want to [rise an error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). In this case in the trigger we need to calculate the week boundaries and fetch the data (question counts) for all employees inserted now (you can insert multiple rows at once and the trigger will fire only once with all new rows in inserted pseudo table). In this case your trigger could look look something like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Contentmenttable_AfterInsert]
   ON [dbo].[Contentmenttable]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET DATEFIRST 1; -- Make Monday first day of the week

    declare @StartOfTheWeek date, @StartOfNextWeek date, @QuestionsCount int, @EmployeeId int

    -- datetiff calculates the number of whole weeks between current date and some other "zero" date
    --  dateadd add back this number of whole weeks to this "zero" date to get the beginning of the current week.
    select @StartOfTheWeek = dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)
    set @StartOfNextWeek = dateadd(day, 7, @StartOfTheWeek)

    -- Get the employee with the highest number of questions returned by the derived table bellow
    select top 1 @QuestionsCount = q.QuestionCount, @EmployeeId = q.EmployeeId
    from (
        -- Calculate number of questions per affected employee for current week
        select count(distinct questionid) as QuestionCount, t.EmployeeId
        from [dbo].[Contentmenttable] t
        -- inserted pseudo table contains the rows that were added to the table
        -- it may contain multiple rows for different employees if we are inserting more than one row at once
        -- e.g. insert into Contentmenttable values(1, 111, '20180101', 0), (2, 222, '20180101', 0)
        where t.EmployeeId in (select EmployeeId from inserted)
          and t.[Date] >= @StartOfTheWeek and t.[Date] < @StartOfNextWeek
        group by t.EmployeeId
    ) q
    order by QuestionsCount desc

    -- If the highest number of questions is more than 10, raise an error and rollback the insert
    if (@QuestionsCount > 10)
        raiserror('EmployeeId %d already has 10 questions this week.', 16, 1, @EmployeeId)
END
GO
```

UPDATE: In case the rows in the table will be inserted only one by one, the code can be simplified. Also it will allow solving the discrepancy with entering rows for past dates, which aren't in the current week. The simplified trigger could be something like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Contentmenttable_AfterInsert]
   ON [dbo].[Contentmenttable]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if (select count(*) from inserted) > 1
        raiserror('Rows in this table should inserted only one by one.', 16, 1)

    SET DATEFIRST 1; -- Make Monday first day of the week

    declare @StartOfTheWeek date, @StartOfNextWeek date, @QuestionsCount int, @EmployeeId int, @Date date

    select @EmployeeId = EmployeeId, @Date = [Date]
    from inserted

    -- datetiff calculates the number of whole weeks between current date and some other "zero" date
    -- dateadd add back this number of whole weeks to this "zero" date to get the beginning of the current week.
    select @StartOfTheWeek = dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, @Date), 0)
    set @StartOfNextWeek = dateadd(day, 7, @StartOfTheWeek)

    -- Calculate number of questions per affected employee for current week
    select @QuestionsCount = count(questionid)
    from [dbo].[Contentmenttable] t
    where t.EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
      and t.[Date] >= @StartOfTheWeek and t.[Date] < @StartOfNextWeek

    -- If the highest number of questions is more than 10, raise an error and rollback the insert
    if (@QuestionsCount > 10)
        raiserror('EmployeeId %d already has 10 questions this week.', 16, 1, @EmployeeId)
END
GO
```

Comment: Could you explain: where t.Employeeid in (select employeeid from inserted). What are you doing here?

Comment: Wow, this is working! Great. But it is hard for me to understand each row. Could you comment each row (what and why you are doing it). Many thanks!!

Comment: Sure! It's setting the first day of the week to be Monday, because by default it should be Sunday. Then it calculates the Monday of the current week and the next Monday. With the derived table it selects the number of questions for each employee, which is inserted with the statement fired the trigger. The inserted rows are in inserted pseudo table, so with this `where EmployeeId in (select EmployeeId from inserted)` it checks only the related employees and not the whole table.Then it selects the one with the highest number of questions and check is it greater than 10.If Yes, it raises an error

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem. If there are more than 10 questions on the same day answered, the trigger does not see it? He only begins to see it when there are two or more different days. How about that?

Comment: There is a typo in my code. Instead of adding 1 week to calculate the next week start, it added 1 day. Please update the calculation of @StartOfNextWeek. Excuse me for the confusion.

Comment: Not detecting questions on same day, but detecting them on different dates doesn't makes sense. It counts the number of questions for a period (between two dates). Could you post the contents of the table and the insert statement, so we can reproduce it, please! Also, is it possible to insert rows, where the date is not today? In this case insertions for older dates may not detect the limit. Is it possible to insert more than one row at a time? If not, the code can be simplified.

Comment: Yes you can insert dates if date is not today, but in 90% of the cases the date is today. And no you can't insert more than one row each time. I added some content of the table contentment, see above.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you the simplified code, if the rows are inserted only one by one. However, your sample data doesn't contain enough rows to detect reaching the limit. If your code still has issues detecting this, post the exact trigger code, insert DML and table contents, please. Otherwise we could not help you finding why it happens

Comment: It works, but it still inserts the employee and questionid to the table. So I think there needs to be a rollback at some point, but I don't know exactly where. I tested it after the raiserror but then I can't insert a new contentement in the table, I get the trigger error message then.

Comment: Yes, this is what I got from your question. Please explain what should happen in all the cases in details.